# Using the CGContext, how do I make either the font italic or bold?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I can use CGContextSelectFont to choose fontType, fontSize.  But how do I make either the font italic or bold?

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the docs for [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_text/dq_text.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH213-TPXREF102)

```
CGContextSelectFont (myContext, // 3
                     "Helvetica-Bold",     // <- Something like this probably
                     h/10,
                     kCGEncodingMacRoman);
```

I've not done any text drawing with Core Graphics so hopefully someone will give a full answer, but it never hurts to look at the docs there is a lot of information in there.

Comment: No it's should be "Helvetica Bold", "Helvetica Italic"